# Why is FFmpeg better discussed at Super User?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, scope

On Stack Overflow, [FFmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ffmpeg/info) has over 6.2k questions, 2.7k (43%) of which are unanswered...

For comparison, on Super User, there are only 1.3k questions about [FFmpeg](https://superuser.com/tags/ffmpeg/info)—of which 500 (38%) are unanswered.

The ratio of asked to answered is similar enough on both sites to the point that the deciding factor would seem to be more for the quantity of questions and answers. For my eyes, this means that Stack Overflow is a **better** resource for getting answers about ffmpeg, because it has a more active community.

So please explain: Why should I post my questions on Super User?

And yes, I do believe shell scripts are programs.

I would also like to know if this means that I should not answer questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: The first ten or so questions are about *using the tool itself*. That's a clear indication. "It runs on a computer, **therefore** it belongs on SO" is not a valid reasoning. Shell scripts can be about *anything*. Does "I want to rename a PDF file" need a [pdf] tag?

Comment: Not necessarily, but according to that logic we would be talking about mp4 needing its own tag - which I am not suggesting. Do you mean that things like sed, grep or imagemagick should also not have tags?

Comment: If you are seeking answer for imagemagick command line, lets say "how to batch convert images", that belongs to super user. If your intention is writing a app with imagemagick API it is SO. If majority keep asking command line help on SO as @Jongware mentioned; It is ok to tell them go super user.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As your stats demonstrate, you stand a reasonable chance of getting an answer on *either* site; therefore, I don't think it makes a whole lot of sense to consider that when making your decision. I recommend [Jeff's old rule of thumb for deciding which site to use](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/why-cant-you-have-just-one-site/) in cases like this:

> Ask yourself this:
>
> - what is your job title?
> - which community do you consider yourself a part of?
> - what are you trying to accomplish?

Are you a programmer, looking for answers from programmers to a problem you've encountered in the course of programming? **Then ask on Stack Overflow!**

Are you a computer enthusiast, looking for answers from other computer enthusiasts to a question that's come up during your enthusiastic use of a computer? **Then ask on Super User!**

Many of us wear both hats and find programming merely one facet of our computer-loving lifestyles - if that describes you as well, then you're left with an easy decision: do you want answers from folks who are more likely to treat your question as a programming problem, or would you be ok with answers from resourceful (but not necessarily code-focused) experts as well?

From a practical standpoint, this tends to mean that questions about the use of ffmpeg by folks who've no desire to script it or integrate it into larger systems belong on SU, while questions that may (or should!) involve scripting/automation belong on SO - but the lines there are fuzzy enough that you can find examples of both on both sites if you look around a bit. And... That's ok.

#### Further reading:

- [Why Can’t You Have Just One Site?](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/why-cant-you-have-just-one-site/)
- [The Pee-Wee Herman Rule](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/the-pee-wee-herman-rule/)
- [Respect the community – your own, and others’](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/)

Comment: The thing that got me was the big disclaimer on the info page: "Questions about using the ffmpeg command line tool are off topic. Please ask them on SuperUser." To me it seemed confusing - which is why I asked this question here.

Comment: @denjello - libavcodec and libavformat questions (which often get tagged with [ffmpeg] because they are part of that project) are clearly programming questions and belong here. The questions about what encoder settings, etc. to pass into the command-line ffmpeg tool to encode video are generally not programming related. They are about the operation of a piece of software and thus have found a good home on Super User. Still, people keep asking here because this is the larger site, just like they do for every other topic, thus the caution in the wiki for that tag.

Comment: I've edited the wiki to (hopefully) clarify this, @denjello. If you're able to answer a programming question regarding ffmpeg, go right ahead and do so; if you think a given question is off-topic, then suggest that the asker posts it on SU and offer to answer it there.

Answer (score 7):

> And yes, I do believe shell scripts are programs.

They are, but questions about shell scripts are only *programming questions* when they are about *using shell script as a programming language* - i.e., something to do with either the syntax or the semantics of that language. So, for example, if you're trying to debug something, and in particular if the problem appears to have something to do with *how a shell script is structured*, above and beyond individual command-line commands.

If the problem has to do with *the actual invocation of the `ffmpeg` command*, then it is a question about ffmpeg - which is a user-space application - and the interface that it provides. That isn't a question about programming.

Note that many of the on-topic [ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ffmpeg) questions on Stack Overflow involve programmatic use of the `ffmpeg` *library* via *bindings* that allow it to be used from other programming languages. The ffmpeg executable isn't actually running, but rather routines from its shared library are called.

Comment: If I were to ask a question about syntax of `print` in `python`, when using `python -c "print(1+1)"` instead of the code in a file, Does `python` suddenly become a user space application and the question off-topic?  Actual invocation shouldn't matter...neither should it matter whether a executable is a "programming language" or application like `chrome` or `inkscape`. Question is whether the syntax is complex enough to be considered programming. If so, the question regardless of type of invocation-  shell/programming languages-bindings/CLI invocation is allowed.

Comment: [Wikipedia defines programming as "Computer programming or coding is the composition of sequences of instructions, called programs, that computers can follow to perform tasks."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_programming). `ffmpeg` CLI invocation is a composition of set of instructions to make the computer  perform certain tasks. Syntax is complex enough to considered programming by computer enthusiasts, if not by developers.

Answer (score 4):

There is https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ffmpeg and probably the best place to ask these questions

Comment: That's probably a good idea. For a subset of the questions in question.