# Cleanup of FFmpeg CLI questions?

Tags: discussion, scope, clean-up

A significant number (most?) of the FFmpeg questions on Stack Overflow are off-topic.  For example:

- [How to add a black bar on top and bottom of a video screen with a watermark on it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43748081/362536)
- [How to generate HLS m3u8 playlist from TS chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43782164/362536)
- [ffmpeg proress 4444 produce low quality output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43761082/362536)

@LordNeckbeard and I seem to be the only ones close-voting these to move them to SuperUser, but as we're only two people the questions are never moved.  Eventually the close votes expire.

Should we stop caring?  And if not, is there any thing we can do to lead a cleanup effort?

To be clear, there are plenty of on-topic use cases for FFmpeg as well, where FFmpeg is used programmatically.  I think those should stay on Stack Overflow.  Also note that there was some previous meta discussion about what types of FFmpeg questions are on-topic:  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267727/362536

Comment: Well, that glass is still half-full.  Two is a crowd.  You'll never be able to close a question and you'll never be able to convince the CMs to do anything about it.   But two is enough to deal with off-topic answers and to get junk *eventually* cleaned-up by the Roomba.  You have to DV to make that work.

Comment: @HansPassant If by "DV" you meant delete... these are often quality questions, just in the wrong places.  There's little sense in outright deleting good content just because it's on the wrong site.

Comment: DV == downvote.  If you think the question is good enough to fit on SU then you can flag a moderator or just tell the questioner about it.

Comment: I asked the question [*Should the ffmpeg tag be banned?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341708/should-the-ffmpeg-tag-be-banned) but people didn't like the idea and Community♦ deleted the question. I'd love to have a close-hammer for [tag:ffmpeg] questions... but there aren't enough of us paying attention to that tag to fend off the eternal inflow of off-topic FFmpeg questions.

Comment: @Cornstalks FFmpeg should absolutely not be banned.  There are plenty of cases where it can be used in a programmatic context... a lot of people use FFmpeg via STDIO and there are situations where there are specific troubles arising from such a setup.  Besides, the questions aren't bad, they're just misplaced.  I usually find FFmpeg questions to be of higher quality than other tags.

Comment: @Cornstalks the moment you think/realize that FFMPEG-related questions should be banned is the moment you should permanently retire your moderator hat.

That being said, I also voted to migrate some ffmpeg-related questions over to SuperUser but did not really care that much to actually see it done.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Whichever way I look at this, it comes down to things that have been hammered out long before my time, in the very design of stackoverflow:  As long as users are allowed to ask questions, there will always be bad ones.

What it comes down to for me:

1. `ffmpeg`, really is an expert topic.  Whether or not it requires specific programming code as part of the question, invoking `ffmpeg` is often programming itself.
2. The quality of answer here is top notch.  I know that this in itself is not a good reason to allow off-topic questions, but when i consider where I myself have learned the vast majority of my `ffmpeg` knowledge, it is from here (and the [ffmpeg docs](https://www.ffmpeg.org/documentation.html) are pretty good, and there's a lot of good wrappers on github).
3. The scope is enormous, and anything much beyond a default `-i input output.mp4` usage (which in itself has a number of implicit options), requires some actual knowledge.  There's also the global syntax vs codec specific syntax which can be very confusing, often undocumented, and requires expert help to operate correctly. - At times I have ended up on github looking at source just to figure out option mappings and deciphering badly worded or missing arguments/options (h264_nvenc, decklink, i'm looking at you).
4. Is it really any different to say `grep`/`sed` questions ?  (not answers that involve the use of `grep`/`sed`).   Most of these that I've seen are either to do with **regex** or the program itself.  Perhaps the answer is no, in which case I think that list could expand quite a lot.
5. Often ffmpeg is wrapped in scripts, such as the black bar example above, or, requires some kind of command line at least to solve certain problems or set certain environment variables.
6. The fact that there are frameworks that allow anyone to compile in third party libraries, without explicit support in the main branch, opens up another world of possible mixtures of technologies, which *may* mean that the most suitable people with the right skillsets to help with these scenarios, are on stackoverflow.

All of those above points really form one big point, which I suppose should be weighed up against how much of a problem it's causing.  I'm too new here to know if `ffmpeg` questions are like weeds.  What I do know is that people are pretty tough here.  There's a lot of questions I haven't had the nerve to ask, so my point here is that if these `ffmpeg` questions have survived, is there perhaps reasons why they were asked here in the first place ?

Comment: I'm not saying these questions shouldn't be asked... I'm suggesting we find a good place for them... even if that place turns out to be StackOverflow.  By definition of site scope alone, SuperUser.com is the best place for questions where FFmpeg isn't used within the context of programming.  Yet, we also have Video StackExchange.  What's happening is that duplicate questions are ending up on all three sites.  The subject matter experts on video processing don't always use all three sites.

Comment: @Brad Agreed, this is the context of most of my thoughts - the fact that rightly or wrongly, the stuff I'd save from a fire would be on StackOverflow

Comment: At the other end of the scale is questions like this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/329747/dont-wait-for-audio-stream-with-ffmpeg-avconv-using-named-pipes - They probably belong in the ffmpeg forums, yet, the question exists, unanswered.  Where StackOverflow would be beneficial for a question like this one (still acknowledging the end of the scale it's at), is the fact that there would be a number of approaches for this problem both using `ffmpeg` options, and/or automating the invocation of `ffmpeg`