# My post keeps getting downvoted for no obvious reason

Tags: discussion, downvotes

I am not very active on my Stack Overflow account and recently asked a question: [Mix multiple audios into one with ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75792819/mix-multiple-audios-into-one-with-ffmpeg)

The question got downvoted to -5, without getting any feedback or answers. In my view, the question itself meets all required criteria.

Because of this, my reputation went down to 1. I consider deleting my question although I answered it myself and it could be helpful to others. Doesn't that go against the spirit of Stack Overflow?

Comment: Using CLI != primarily programming. You're asking for a command line solution, not a programming one. The answer illustrates this perfectly as it's "use a different tool". The question belongs on [su] or [unix.se].

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267726/208273, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/348892/208273

Comment: I don't think we need an update for every vote the question gets. Also note that by posting you've accelerated the number of votes you'd get due to [the meta effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269349/what-is-the-meta-effect)

Comment: Is there a meta meta stackoverflow where I can ask why my question about getting downvotes gets downvoted?

Comment: [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) I suppose. But questions about "why the downvotes" generally get downvoted anyway.

Comment: Meta Stack Overflow is its own meta site, so that would be on-topic here (and off-topic on Meta Stack Exchange, really).  But it's not really necessary to ask, as we can discuss it here: in general (as @VLAZ notes), posts complaining about downvotes tend to get downvoted, as people tend not to see them as useful (contrast with asking _why_ a question was downvoted and how/if you could improve it).

Comment: The word toxic gets thrown around so much on meta that it has lost all meaning. Down-voted? Toxic. Don't want to deal with off-topic questions? Toxic. As for the comparison with other Stack Exchange sites: take a look at the new questions page. The 50th question on the physics site was asked 18 hours ago. For Stack Overflow, that was 10 minutes (!) ago. It's a lot easier to care about every single question when you get less than a 100 per day.

Comment: You think we should allow cookery questions, or physics or chemistry questions? We draw the line where we do and in this case there's a site that probably will accept your question/answer and where it likely will get upvotes. Do remember voting is not toxic, rude comments are but you don't seem to have any of those.

Comment: I don't think the comparison to cookery questions is entirely apt here.  I mean really this is at least _close_ to the line of programming; it involves a bash script in the question. It may not be clearly about programming (the answer first suggests a non-programming solution) but there's certainly some programming involved here.  It could be titled "bash script that mixes multiple audio files using ffmpeg" and move the suggestion to use a different CLI tool to the end of the answer, and it'd be pretty arguably on-topic.

Comment: @RyanM deliberate hyperbole. Wherever the line is there will be questions on one side or the other and ones we will all disagree on.

Comment: Imagine a newcomer like me sees an ffmpeg-question like mine upvoted 541 times: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937387/rotating-videos-with-ffmpeg, except this one doesn't even include scripting. Why should I assume I'm on the wrong stackexchange? Why did no one close that question because it "is not about programming or software development"? This all looks pretty arbitrary to me.

Comment: @Kunibert: Stack Overflow evolves, and some (well, many) old questions, once being suitable for Stack Overflow, are no longer on-topic here. When ask a new question, it is always useful to read excerpt in the tags you are using. E.g. [excerpt in ffmpeg tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ffmpeg/info) says: "Only questions about programmatic use of the FFmpeg libraries, API, or tools are on topic. Questions about interactive use of the command line tool should be asked on Super User or Video Production."

Comment: " Why did no one close that question because it "is not about programming or software development"?" Well, it is closed now. Due to sheer volume of questions asked on daily basis, Stack Overflow lacks volunteers that moderate site and close unsuitable questions. Because of that you cannot rely on existing questions (even highly upvoted ones) when trying to figure out whether your question is on topic or not. Help center has a number of articles that can help you, but you can also ask here on SO Meta if you have some doubts whether question you want to ask will be on topic for the site.

Comment: "*Why did no one close that question because it "is not about programming or software development"?*" consider the following: [the downvote privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) requires 125 reputation, while [the close vote privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) requires 3000 reputation. So there is a big gap between the two where somebody can downvote but not close vote. They can *flag* to close but that adds a post to the close votes review queue. A post still requires three close votes to be closed for "Not about programming" 1/2

Comment: The close votes queue has [about 3k items in it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9dXb.png) which is close enough to its usual state. Point being there is a lot to review. You can see that [your post *was in the queue*](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75792819/timeline#review_34071893) the date Mar 20 is when it entered. The timestamp is from about 20 minutes after you posted. So the answer is underwhelmingly that not enough people saw the question to vote for closure. Before the meta effect. What you call "arbitrary" is simply being short-handed. 2/2

Comment: (Bonus! 3/2) [Stack Overflow gets 4.4k questions *per day*](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday). That's also *on average* - over the weekend the activity is lower, so there are less questions. Over the work week we do get more than the average. So, if you are wondering why *your question* was somehow singled out and not looked at - no, there are just too many coming in to properly examine each and every one each and every single day. Again, short-handedness, rather than deliberately trying to apply rules in a random fashion.

Comment: I had completely forgotten that there *is* a close vote queue.

Comment: It looks as though you tried to create a text file with some bash script in it, and then told ffmpeg to use that file's contents as a list of input files. Aside from being clearly wrong, the underlying question is about **how to use a program** (ffmpeg). That's even more clearly "not programming". If the question were about debugging a bash script then that does fit, but from what you showed, it doesn't look like the steps you took actually involved running a bash script.

Comment: In this case using the program for an undefined number of input arguments requires list concatenation in some form, which can be considered a programming problem. Besides, Stackoverflow is full of threads about how to use ffmpeg. Some popular questions got asked in 2020, and some got edited by high reputation users in 2021, with rep > 3000. Did those editors just not care the questions violate the SO regulations or didn't they know better? I get the impression questions get tolerated as long as they're popular enough. Leaving newcomers confused is of course a consequence of this, Karl. 1/2

Comment: In my question the bash script is meant to create the text file which is needed as an input for `ffmpeg`. Creating the text file involves iterating over file names. In this case a for-loop, which is considered programming by most people. [bash tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) supports my point of view. 2/2

Comment: In that case you can just remove the `ffmpeg` part and make it on topic, right? _How to loop over filenames in bash to concatenate arguments for a program?_, for example. It's probably been asked and answered before though

Answer (score -5):

The discussion in the comment section above resulted in the following: 
The referred thread isn't a suitable question for Stack Overflow, because accessing a command line tool (`ffmpeg`) via a bash script isn't exactly a programming problem. Therefore the thread got closed. To avoid getting downvoted because of similar reasons, one should keep in mind:

1. You must not rely on comparing your question with other existing questions regarding on-topic-criteria, as they might not (or no longer) meet the Stack Overflow criteria for asking questions. It's in the poster's responsibility to ask only on-topic questions.
2. Before posting a question, you should read the rules of the tags you use for the question. These contain information about what issues are considered on-topic in this regard.
3. The more popular a Stack Exchange Community is, the more important it gets to follow the rules. This is crucial for moderators to be able to manage the topics.
   The better known a community is, the smaller the proportion of voluntary moderators seems to get in relation to the total number of users. This just further increases the importance of following the rules in order to minimise administratory workload.
4. Closing a question requires 24 times more reputation than downvoting a post (3000 instead of 125). This makes it more likely a misplaced question gets downvoted instead of closed.